# How to color only a "tilde" accent on a letter?

Tags: math-mode, color

I would like to color only a "tilde" on my letters. I read how to do this with Umlauts or other accent, but for my expression it seems different I think. Here is my expression :

```
\widetilde{E}^w
```

So, is there a way to color only the tilde and not the E^w ?
Someone already has implemented it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm)

Comment: Very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46701/how-to-color-just-the-vec-symbol?rq=1

Comment: @Torbjorn Yes indeed, i'm not used to the site yet to find easily the answer to my question ^^

Comment: Updated my answer: the exponent `w` was not close enough to `E`.

Comment: @B_runo There is a special problem with skewchar. I described this in detail in the http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46701/how-to-color-just-the-vec-symbol because this post is closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing color is not really supported, so you lose some metric information and a manual correction could be needed in some cases:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xcolor}

\newcommand{\colorwt}[2][2]{%
  {}\mspace{#1mu}\mathrlap{\textcolor{red}{\widetilde{\phantom{#2}}}}%
  \mspace{-#1mu}#2%
}

\begin{document}
X$\widetilde{E}^{w}$X$\widetilde{I}$X

X$\colorwt{E}^{w}$X$\colorwt{I}$X

X$\colorwt[3]{E}^{w}$X$\colorwt[3]{I}$X

X$\colorwt[2]{E}^{w}$X$\colorwt[2]{I}$X

X$\colorwt[1]{E}^{w}$X$\colorwt[1]{I}$X
\end{document}
```

The default value of the manual correction is `2`, I have shown what's the effect when you specify a different value.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Quite simply:

```
 $\textcolor{red}{\widetilde{\textcolor{black}{E\,}}}²!^w $
```

I had to make a small correction to have a correct positioning of the accent, though.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Grouping does the work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}


${\color{green}\widetilde{\color{black}{E}}}^w$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it, see the link below :

[How to color over/underline, or other ways to highlight substituted expressions in proofs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57070/55960)

and change \overline in the newcommand by \widetilde or any accent you want.