# Multiple signature lines based on \author{} size

Tags: macros, titles

I am trying to create a .cls file for use by multiple users for generating `\documentclass{article}` documents. Inside this class, I want a macro/script to be able to automatically generate a signature line for every entry in the `\author{}` field. I know `\@author` contains the information; how do I read the size of `\@author` to know how many lines to create (or is this the wrong path to be going down)?

EDIT:

Upon further review of TEX.SX questions, I learned where `\and` was defined and consequently how redefining `\and` could include the `\vspace` and `\rule` for additional authors. My successful solution is listed below.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{newclass}

\author{Neil Armstrong\\Commander
       \and
        Buzz Aldrin\\Lunar Module Pilot
       \and
        Michael Collins\\Command Module Pilot}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

using newclass.cls

```
\ProvidesClass{newclass}
\LoadClass{article}

\def\and{%                  % \begin{tabular}
  \end{tabular}%
  \vspace{2ex}\\
  and\\
  \vspace{0.5in}
  \rule{4cm}{0.4pt}\\
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}}%   % \end{tabular}
```

Comment: Ho are you adding the `and\\ ` and the spaces? Can't you just append the code for the rule?

Comment: You are correct. After posting this question, I stumbled on other "too many authors on one line" topics and realized I could redefine the `\and` parameter within `\author` to include the new lines and `\rule`. I need to edit this subject\question, as I am now curious if I can include the `\def\and` in the .cls file rather than the .tex file's preamble.

Comment: You just wrote in your edit, that you were succesful. Can you add your solution as an answer to the question below? It helps keeping the place tidy.

Comment: I would use `\par` between the different parts to avoid warnings about underful boxes.

Comment: @Johannes_B, understood, I will add it as answer; for your `\par` comment, can you expand? Are you saying replace the `\vspace` instances? Currently, I do not have underfill errors (but I have only ranged between 1-5 signature lines).

Comment: The title is typeset centered. You can forget my comment, it doesn't matter. Sorry for the confusiion.

Comment: Idea: print the `\author` in white text colour and underline it with another colour, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57070/how-to-color-over-underline-or-other-ways-to-highlight-substituted-expressions. This should give you lines corresponding to the author content.

Answer (score 1):

Upon further review of TEX.SX questions, I learned where `\and` was defined and consequently how redefining `\and` could include the `\vspace` and `\rule` for additional authors. My successful solution is listed below.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{newclass}

\author{Neil Armstrong\\Commander
       \and
        Buzz Aldrin\\Lunar Module Pilot
       \and
        Michael Collins\\Command Module Pilot}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

using newclass.cls

```
\ProvidesClass{newclass}
\LoadClass{article}

\def\and{%                  % \begin{tabular}
\end{tabular}%
\vspace{2ex}\\
and\\
\vspace{0.5in}
\rule{4cm}{0.4pt}\\
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}}%   % \end{tabular}
```

Comment: It's fine to answer your own question, but as this is the answer I'd delete it from the question:)